# Eigenvectors of $n^{th}$ root of identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A^n=I,$ where $A$ is $n\times n,$ and assume that $A^k\neq I,$ for all $1\leq k<n.$ Since its characteristic polynomial is $x^n-1$, the distinct $n^{th}$ roots of unity are its eigenvalues,

Thus there are a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors.

- What do they look like?
- If we assume $A$ is orthogonal, what do they look like?
- If we assume $A$ is real, can one say anything more?

Comment: Hint: since the eigenvalues are distinct it follows the eigenvectors are linearly independent and $A$ is diagonalizable. So write $A=USU^*$.

Comment: They can look like anything in general, in the sense that they can literally be any basis of the underlying vector space.

Comment: The roots are not necessarily distinct. For that you need that $A^{n-1}\ne I$.

Comment: Please see edit, thanks for the comment.